# Is any possibility to store float values to id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I want the float value as it is how to do that ....some one help me :)

```
 id count;
 float v=2.00; 
 id=@(2.00);//@()this is number so my value get rounded from float to integer
 Nslog(@"%@",count);// answer is 2
```

my expected is 2.00

Comment: 2 and 2.00 are the same thing, how you print the value is up to you...

Comment: indeed it does, but that's a different question in some ways and doesn't affect that it's a printing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print value is 2 or 2.00 are the same values.

```
 NSLog(@"%.2f", v); // answer is 2.00
```

For display in UILabel

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", v];
```

Comment: to print this ok , but i am using my id (i.e) v to display values in label bro .....

Comment: if its coming value is 8.23 then if i display what it will show

Comment: @KishoreKumar It will display 8.23

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a pointer to an objective c object, in the case of cocoa generally an `NSObject`, so you need to wrap your float in an **NSNumber** (which inherits from **NSObject**).

`NSNumber` can handle many other primitive types.

```
float no = 3.0;
NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:no];
```